# Feed grep output to xargs

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

I'm trying to feed grep output into xargs, but nothing is happening.
I have the following command (without grep) that works just fine:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log|\ 
awk '{print "insert or ignore into referrer (url) values (" $11 ");"}'|\ 
sqlite3 referrer.sqlite3
```

What this basically does is monitor my nginx access log and write all the referrers it can find into a SQLite database. However, I don't want to write *all* referrers into the database, I want to filter out some, so I adjusted the command to this:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log|\
awk '{print "insert or ignore into referrer (url) values (" $11 ");"}'|\
grep -Ev '("https?://www.bing.com/|"https?://(m|www).facebook.com("|/)|"-")'
```

This filters out any access requests with Bing or Facebook as a referrer, as well as filter out requests without referrer. This still works fine. However, I cannot forward the output from this command into either sqlite or xargs. When I append:

```
|sqlite3 referrer.sqlite3
```

Or

```
|xargs sqlite3 referrer.sqlite3
```

Nothing happens, it doesn't seem to get any input. Also when I use `xargs echo` to echo the command rather than execute it, nothing is shown. I also tried adding a `-Z` to the grep and a `-0` to xargs, so they both use a null-byte instead of a newline. But, this also didn't help anything.

What am I missing? Why is the output of my command not "forwardable" after the grep?

Comment: You do not need back-quotes after the pipe symbol at the end of a line.

Comment: Add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to you question.

Comment: Just to make sure that `grep` produces output, you can add a `tee /dev/stderr` process in between `grep` and `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` and `awk` commands are line buffered by default when writing to a pipe. You must inform them you wish to be less efficient (lose performance).

```
awk -W interactive
grep --line-buffered
```

Add these option to your commands to avoid buffering.